# Obsolete data mask. x Too late to resolve `XXX` after the end of `dplyr::summarise()`

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a following problem. I have two dataframes (df1 and df2) and I want to calculate a mean of them. I read data from xls, so I show you a print screen of my dataframe, because I don`t know how to name columns "1.", "2." etc.

[image]

I use this code:

```
df_together <- bind_rows(df1 %>% add_rownames(), 
                          df2 %>% add_rownames()) %>% 
  # evaluate following calls for each value in the rowname column
  group_by(rowname) %>% 
  # mean
  summarise_all(mean)
```

This code worked a year ago, but know I get this error message. I don`t know, what this error means:

```
<error/rlang_error>
Obsolete data mask.
x Too late to resolve `měsíc` after the end of `dplyr::summarise()`.
i Did you save an object that uses `měsíc` lazily in a column in the `dplyr::summarise()` expression ?
Backtrace:
     x
  1. +-`%>%`(...)
  2. \-dplyr::summarise_all(., mean)
  3.   +-dplyr::summarise(.tbl, !!!funs)
  4.   \-dplyr:::summarise.grouped_df(.tbl, !!!funs)
  5.     \-dplyr:::summarise_cols(.data, ...)
  6.       \-mask$forget("summarise")
  7.         +-base::suppressWarnings(...)
  8.         | \-base::withCallingHandlers(expr, warning = function(w) invokeRestart("muffleWarning"))
  9.         +-rlang::env_bind_lazy(bindings, !!!set_names(promises, names_bindings))
 10.         \-dplyr:::osbolete_promise_fn("mesíc")
```

How can I fix it please? This did not help me: [Obsolete data mask. Too late to resolve `xxxxxx` after the end of `dplyr::mutate()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66614397/obsolete-data-mask-too-late-to-resolve-xxxxxx-after-the-end-of-dplyrmutate)

Comment: This is working for me on `dplyr` 1.0.4` `bind_rows(mtcars %>% add_rownames(), mtcars %>% add_rownames()) %>% group_by(rowname) %>% summarise_all(mean)`  But, there is a recommendation to use `tibble::rownames_to_column()` and `summarise(across(everything(), mean))`

Comment: Is it the `rownames_to_column` or `summarise(across`

Comment: @akrun it`s the `summarise(across(everything(), mean))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the newer versions of `dplyr`, it is recommended to replace the `add_rownames` with `tibble::rownames_to_column` and the `summarise_all` with `summarise(across`.  Using a reproducible example

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
    tibble::rownames_to_column() %>%
    bind_rows(mtcars %>%
        tibble::rownames_to_column()) %>%
    group_by(rowname) %>%
    summarise(across(everything(), mean, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'drop')
```